# Javascript module pattern - Can all modules access eachother?

Tags: javascript, design-patterns

I've done a fair amount with vanilla javascript and jquery. I'm trying to write an app now that uses some form of closures to privatize methods so that everything isn't just out in the public namespace.

I turned to the Module Pattern, because it seemed to be the solution to my problems, however I can't quite wrap my head around it. When you use this pattern to add methods onto the main app, can all of the modules use all of the methods from other modules too? Because, it seems like that is not the case.

```
var MODULE = (function () {
    var my = {},
        privateVariable = 1;

    function privateMethod() {
        // ...
    }

    my.moduleProperty = 1;
    my.moduleMethod = function () {
        console.log("Method 1!");
    };
    my.anotherMethod(); //This doesn't work. anotherMethod() not     defined
    return my;
}());

var MODULETWO = (function (my) {
    my.anotherMethod = function () {
        console.log("Method 2!");
    };
    my.moduleMethod();
    my.anotherMethod();
    return my;
}(MODULETWO));
```

For some reason I would expect the commented method to work. Can we make that work?  I envision having an app.js with the meat of an app, with other separate js files that have utility functions to help that app, but in a lot of cases I envision those utility classes needing access to the main app's scope.  I can't seem to get that...

Thoughts?

Someone I talked to pointed me to Browserify.js, but I don't know if that solves my requirement of having everything inaccessible via closures.  It seems just like a bundling app.

Comment: Do you intend to pass `MODULE` when invoking `MODULETWO`, is it a typo? Even then it would never work, since `MODULE` knows nothing about `MODULETWO` where the method is being added to the object.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that you don't adhere to Object Oriented Design rules. There are various paradigms to this, and more books, blogs and videos then you could consume in 10 lifetimes. Personally I recommend the SOLID principles for OOP.

More specifically, your modules should serve as encapsulated units. A module should have a single logical responsibility that should be exposed through its public methods. If you need access to its private methods, you have a design problem.

Answer (score 0):

The adhoc module pattern gives you a way to create privacy by enclosing a value inside of a function, thus a closure.

Think of it this way:

If you declare a variable inside a function, it can only be accessed in that function, unless you expose it.

Unexposed, _foo just sits there waiting for garbage collection

```
var foo = function() {
    _foo = {name: 'joe', age: 42};
};
var myFoo = new foo();//this is undefined as we return nothing
```

Exposed, name is exposed but age is not, you can't access _foo directly. In the code below age is useless because it can't be reached.

```
var foo = function() {
    _foo = {name: 'joe', age: 42};
    var api = {
        getName: function() {
            return _foo.name;//api can return this because _foo is still in scope
        }

};
var myFoo = new foo();//this is an object with one method, getName (it is the api returned from foo).
```

If you create another constructor, bar, it will not be able to interact with _foo, since it is trapped inside of myFoo. bar's api can only access variables defined inside of it, in this case _bar.

```
var bar = function() {
    _bar = {name: 'mike', age: 4};
    var api = {
        getName: function() {
            return _foo.name;
        },
        getAge: function() {
            return _bar.age
        hasBirthday: function() {
            _bar.age++;
            return _bar.age;//bumps the age and returns the new age.
        }

};
```

Notice bar takes full advantage of the private data, it might be a good idea to add setters.

This pattern provides privacy, the architecture of how you structure your app is totally up to you.

Check out this book for comprehensive examples of fundemental Javascript patterns: https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/